# Windows Phone 7 and IE DOM Performance

Tags: javascript, dom, windows-phone-7

I have been creating a Javascript/jQuery heavy application for Windows Phones and iPhones.
The app is very nearly complete (bar a few little features), however the performance slowly degrades after periods of use on a Windows Phone 7 (IE9 Mango).

It starts off very fast, but after a few DOM changes (appending and removing etc) - Clicking buttons has a bit of lag - then almost a whole second of lag per click a little while after that!

I was just wondering if there was a way to "refresh" the DOM? or some way of resetting the DOM cache (if it even has one?)

Maybe I'm missing something obvious...

Any ideas?

Thanks people!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you say performance slowly degrades, there is a good chance this is a memory problem.

You can test your page on desktop to see if you have the similar problem. Here are ways to test:

- http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/
  This is the best tool if you want to improve performance in IE. It is complex, but shows an incredible amount of data about your site.
- http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/08/finding-memory-leaks.html You can also use chrome memory profiling, like the article describes.

Also these would improve performance:

- Optimize jQuery selectors
- Don't make DOM manipulation in loops, store your html in a string or array, and append that to the DOM
- Try techniques mentioned here : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU